# How can I induce quality factor?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm trying to induce Quality factor of RLC circuit.

In series, I did it with Frequency responce
$$ H(s) = R/(R+sL+1/sC) = (something)/(s^2+2sw_0\zeta+w_0^2)$$
And
$$Q=1/2\zeta$$
But I can't find how to induce it in parallel.

Comment: Multiply numerator and denominator by sC.

Comment: Actually that equation came from RLC series circuit, and I found Quality factor with $$Q=Root(L/C)*1/R$$. I'm trying to find parallel one.

Comment: By the way, ee.se uses `\$` to start and end inline math.

Comment: I tried to use root or divide symbol but failed... I used $$. Do you know how to use them?

Comment: You can write `\$\sqrt{L/R}\$`, for example, to get a square root symbol (\$\sqrt{L/R}\$).

Comment: $$\sqrt{L/R}$$ got it

Comment: My main point was that `$$` makes "display math" (on its own line, while `\$` makes in-line math.

Comment: \$\sqrt{L/R}\$ got that too. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did the math you would find that the \$2\zeta\omega_0\$ term comes out as \$\frac{1}{CR}\$.

Knowing that \$\omega_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$ you can compute zeta as equal to \$\frac{1}{2R}\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$.

You know how to turn zeta into Q so no need to restate that.

---

**Explanation**

You have to imagine driving the parallel RLC from a current source because a current source has infinite output impedance and therefore its impedance doesn't alter the circuit values. Next you turn the current source and the parallel resistance of the RLC into a voltage source and series resistor. Again, I stress no impedances or math is harmed in this re-arrangement!

You then can make a sensible TF of the new circuit: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcgGvr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$H(s) = \dfrac{X_L||X_C}{R + X_L||X_C}\$

Where \$X_L||X_C = \dfrac{\frac{sL}{sC}}{sL + 1/sC} = \dfrac{sL}{1+s^2LC}\$

Stuff it in the formula and you get: -

\$H(s) = \dfrac{sL}{R + s^2LCR + sL}\$

Next, divide through by LCR to get: -

\$H(s) = \dfrac{\frac{s}{CR}}{s^2 + \frac{s}{CR} + \frac{1}{LC}}\$

Now it's in standard form for recognizing that \$\frac{1}{CR} = 2\zeta\omega_0\$. Continue to find zeta as per my original answer.

Comment: That one was about series RLC circuit. I'm trying to find parallel quality factor.

Comment: My formula IS zeta for a parallel RLC. Do the algebra to simply convert to Q.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your answer. Your formula is right. How can I induce that formula?

Comment: I'll add explanation to my answer. Give me a few minutes....

Comment: I'll wait for you. Thx

Comment: Done (hopefully).

Comment: This is answer I wanted. I understand most of them. Thanks a lot, again. The only thing I can't understand is,  numerator. What exactly should I use in numerator when I try to find frequency response?

Comment: For the equivalent of a bode plot (|H(s)|) swap s for jw. Are you aware it's a bandpass filter centred at \$\sqrt{1/LC}\$

Comment: I mean, I thought that numerator should be R, not \$X_L||X_C\$

Comment: It is what it is the way I have derived it. If you have a different circuit in mind that you want the TF for then I'm not aware of it. Maybe you think that at resonance the TF won't be unity - if so I can assure you that it will be (more math needed of course).

Comment: Got it. I'm really appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

How did you derive the transfer function for the series circuit? Answer: Complex voltage divider. Why didn`t you try this method also for the parallel combination? Then, if you manipulate the resulting function with the aim to have again a quadratic polynominal in the denominator you can identify the wanted parameter.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure how to make transfer function in parallel RLC circuit. I did it in series $$H(s) = (I*V_R)/(I*V_s)$$ because current is same in series. But how should I do in parallel?

Comment: I am afraid, you have a wrong circuit arrangement in mind. I suppose, you speak about voltage-in and voltage-out, correct? So you need a complex voltage divider.

Comment: I thought that H(s) is ratio of voltage out and voltage in. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Yes - that is the definition.

Comment: But in parallel, voltage is same in R, L, C. Then H(s) should be 1? Or parallel RLC circuit use different definition?

Comment: The problem was that you didn`t know the circuit you wanted to analyze.